# Передача больших текстовых данных через SOAP

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, soap, веб-служба

Есть необходимость отдавать через SOAP сервис большие объемы текстовых данных (6-30 МБ). Как это лучше сделать?

Сейчас рассматриваю два варианта:

1. Включение zip/gzip сжатия на сервере приложений;
2. Паковать данные в zip-архив и отдавать их base64 строкой.

Если нет более вменяемого решения, то какое решение посоветуете?

Сервер приложений: apache tomcat

Фреймворк: Spring WS

ЯП: Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если именно текст, то оба варианты приемлимы. Если нужно бинарные данные передавать то для этого есть MTOM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Transmission_Optimization_Mechanism